# Thermal Printing using TCP

Tags: java, android-studio, bitmap, thermal-printer, wifi-print

I have a android app that prints a receipt bitmap and when im printing it using usb it prints and cuts fine, but print using TCP, it take so much time to cut the paper eventhough the receipt is already printed. what would be the issue? I use android studio,Java and a Epson thermal printer.

I tried print using a pagelist that every page has a 10 lines. not worked

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the relevant code and any information which will help in answering.